# Interaction Failed (DiscordJS v13)

Tags: discord.js, discord-buttons

No error message, it just keep saying interaction failed
please help me which part is wrong
I want to make a rock,paper, scissor command.
So basically how this works, I click a button, and the bot will randomly pick another/same button.
and the winner will get 1 point. after some time, the winner is the one with most points
I have to put some stuff because "ur post is mostly code"
like I just want this thing to work man..

````
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, Discord } = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = new Command({
    name: 'rps',
    description: "play rock paper scissors",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        let botPick;
        let botEmoji;
        let botChoose;
        let playerScore = 0;
        let botScore = 0;
        let rock = ":fist: Rock";
        let paper = ":hand_splayed: Paper";
        let scissor = ":v: Scissor";

        const rockButton = new MessageButton().setCustomId("rock").setStyle('SECONDARY').setLabel("Rock");
        const paperButton = new MessageButton().setCustomId("paper").setStyle('SECONDARY').setLabel("Paper");
        const scissorButton = new MessageButton().setCustomId("scissor").setStyle('SECONDARY').setLabel("Scissor");

        const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents([rockButton, paperButton, scissorButton]);

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setDescription("Winner: **-**")
        .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] }).then((message) => {
            const ifilter = i => i.user.id === message.author.id;
            const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: ifilter, time: 30000 })

            collector.on("collect", async i => {
                button.deferUpdate();

                botPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
                if (botPick === 1) {
                    botChoose = "rock";

                }
                if (botPick === 2) {
                    botChoose = "paper";
                    
                }
                if (botPick === 3) {
                    botChoose = "scissor";
                    
                }

                let embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setDescription('Winner: **-**')
                .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)

                if (button.id === "rock") {
                    botPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

                    if (botChoose === "paper") {
                        botScore++;
                        let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setDescription('Winner: **-**')
                        .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${paper}**\nYou picked: **${rock}**\n**Result**: You lost`, embeds: [embed2], components: [row] })
                    }
                    if (botChoose === "rock") {
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${rock}**\nYou picked: **${rock}**\n**Result**: We tied`, embeds: [embed1], components: [row] })
                    }
                    if (botChoose === "scissor") {
                        playerScore++;
                        let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setDescription('Winner: **-**')
                        .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${scissor}**\nYou picked: **${rock}**\n**Result**: You Won`, embeds: [embed2], components: [row] })
                    }
                }

                if (button.id === "paper") {
                    botPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

                    if (botChoose === "scissor") {
                        botScore++;
                        let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setDescription('Winner: **-**')
                        .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${scissor}**\nYou picked: **${paper}**\n**Result**: You lost`, embeds: [embed2], components: [row] })
                    }
                    if (botChoose === "paper") {
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${paper}**\nYou picked: **${paper}**\n**Result**: We tied`, embeds: [embed1], components: [row] })
                    }
                    if (botChoose === "rock") {
                        playerScore++;
                        let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setDescription('Winner: **-**')
                        .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${rock}**\nYou picked: **${paper}**\n**Result**: You Won`, embeds: [embed2], components: [row] })
                    }
                }

                if (button.id === "scissor") {
                    botPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

                    if (botChoose === "rock") {
                        botScore++;
                        let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setDescription('Winner: **-**')
                        .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${rock}**\nYou picked: **${scissor}**\n**Result**: You lost`, embeds: [embed2], components: [row] })
                    }
                    if (botChoose === "scissor") {
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${scissor}**\nYou picked: **${scissor}**\n**Result**: We tied`, embeds: [embed1], components: [row] })
                    }
                    if (botChoose === "paper") {
                        playerScore++;
                        let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .setDescription('Winner: **-**')
                        .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                        return message.edit({ content: `I picked: **${paper}**\nYou picked: **${scissor}**\n**Result**: You Won`, embeds: [embed2], components: [row] })
                    }
                }

                collector.on("end", async(x) => {
                    if (x.size === 0) {
                        message.edit(`No one even played againts me lol!`, null);
                    } else if (x.size > 0) {
                        if (playerScore === botScore) {
                            let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor("BLACK")
                            .setDescription('Winner: **TIED**')
                            .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                            message.edit({ content: [null], embeds: [embed2], components: [null] })
                        } else if (playerScore > botScore) {
                            let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor("GREEN")
                            .setDescription(`Winner: **${message.author}**`)
                            .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                            message.edit({ content: [null], embeds: [embed2], components: [null] })
                        } else if (playerScore < botScore) {
                            let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor("RED")
                            .setDescription(`Winner: **${client.user}**`)
                            .addField(`Score RPS`, `\`->\` ${message.author}: **${playerScore} Point**\n\`->\` ${client.user}: **${botScore} Point**`)
                            message.edit({ content: [null], embeds: [embed2], components: [null] })
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 1):

Note that you cecked the wrong value of the button id

use button.customId instead of button.id this is not a correct to check the id.

Also on your collector there is so many resource embed create , practicaly this is a bad idea considering using one function to handle that win and lose :)

for making collector recognized what the component you been using you need to declare the type of components.

Like this.

```
const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({
 filter: ifilter,
 componenType: "BUTTON",
 time: 30000
})
```

Its seem your collector did not recognized your component.

Answer (score 0):

In your `collector.on("collect", ...)`'s callback, you take a parameter `i`, but use `button.deferUpdate()` in the body of the function. `button` is not defined, result in an error, and the interaction times out.

In addition, your `message.channel.send(...).then(message)` overwrites the original `message` variable, so your filter is actually looking for interactions from the bot itself.

To fix this, remove the unnecessary variable `message` from the `.then()`:

```js
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] }).then(() => {
  // ...
```

Also, change the parameter's name from `i` to `button`:

```js
collector.on("collect", async button => {
  button.deferUpdate();
  // ...
}
```

Another issue is that `collector.on("end")` is called within `collector.on("collect")`. This may be unintended, and you may want to move that outside of the `collector.on("collect")` callback function.

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console when this happens? Also, if you try logging something in the `collector.on("collect")` callback, does it run?

Comment: @JerBlox I have updated my answer to include another issue preventing the command from working

Comment: no no, no errors, I literally said it at the first sentence, it just when I click the button it says "interaction failed"

Comment: Yes, I got that. And I am pretty sure I have addressed all the issues causing the "interaction failed." I have tested a version of the code in my answer with my bot, and it works now